# AFNetworking 2.0 Setting Content Type

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am basically building my app like the AFNetworking example that you can download from the AFNetworking 2.0 GitHub. However, in the past with AFNetworking 1.0 when I made a Client network extension class, I had to specify the `initWithBaseURL` that I can set acceptable content type.

In 2.0, it seems in the example does not have this instance method anymore. So, when I am using a web service, I am getting error `[1]  (null)  @"NSLocalizedDescription" : @"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"`

I tried the method of not using a AFClient class, and it works, but I want to set it up like the example, so I can have better code reuse.

Where can I set the contentType? Also, in the example for 2.0, they have a block call
`+ (NSURLSessionDataTask *)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block {` Before the return type would be `void`. What's the purpose of returning a `NSURLSessionDataTask`?

Comment: Regarding your second question regarding `globalTimelinePostsWithBlock`, if you look at how it's used in the demonstration, you'll see that they then pass the task object to `UIAlertView+AFNetworking` method `showAlertViewForTaskWithErrorOnCompletion`. You couldn't do that if you didn't get the task object back. In fact, that was one of the problems with AFNetworking 1.x methods like `+[AFHTTPClient getPath:...]`, that they used `void` in circumstances where you really needed to get the object back.

Comment: @Rob thank you for the response, so it's basically saying if there is an error in the call, show an alertview? Is there really any big advantage to this? Couldn't I just put an `else` after the `if(!error)` and show a `UIAlertview` with the `[error description]` like it was done in AF1.0?

Comment: The only obvious advantage I can see is if the task was added to a background session (because getting the task identifier is the only way you could re-instantiate the alerts after your app is restarted, though you'd have to store task identifiers in persistent storage). Regardless, I think that as a general design principle, it makes sense to always return the relevant object, because you never know when you might need it in the future. I think 1.x was returning voids in many situations where it should have been returning objects. This has been somewhat remedied in 2.0.

Comment: @Rob ahh... thank you. I learn to use this style. Do you happen to know the answer to the 1st question? I still lost to where to set the responseSerializer, if I am subclassing the `AFHTTPSessionManager` like in the example.

Comment: Yep, I see your answer, and you nailed it. Damien identified the crux of the solution in the second part of his answer, and you've correctly identified the right place to do it. (There's no point in trying to setting class properties until the object has been instantiated.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the content-type of your response is text/html.

To get it, set the response Serializer of your AFHTTPSessionManager like that:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

or you can try

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Comment: I believe you definitely want to do the latter, as the former will affect what content types will be accepted, but won't stop the default serializer, `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, from trying to parse the response as JSON when it comes back. By completely changing the `responseSerializer`, as in your second example, you bypass that issue.

Comment: @Damien but where do I add this bit of code? I know where to add it if I just create a AFSessionManager object and set it, but since I am doing it like the example the AFHTTPSessionManager is subclassed by the `AFAppDotNetAPIClient`. I am not sure where to set the responseSerializer. I tried putting it in the subclass in the `sharedClient` class method using code `_sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPREsponseSerializer serializer]`, but it's not working.

Comment: @alan you answered to your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I was setting the responseSerializer before the allocation... -_-. You need to put it int he sharedClient class method.

```
 + (instancetype)sharedClient {
static AFMobileClient *_sharedClient = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;


//_sharedClient.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    _sharedClient = [[AFMobileClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseURLString]];
    //_sharedClient.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
    _sharedClient.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
});

return _sharedClient;
}
```